# How can convert PDF To Word Using Ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, ghostscript

Can Any One Tell Me How Can We Convert PDF To Word Using Ghostscript..?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, Ghostscript doesn't do that.

On the current version of Ghostscript you can use the txtwrite device to get text from the PDF file, and make some stab at maintaining the layout using spaces. You could import that into word.